# Arrays and print statements/ java

Tags: java

I need to make a program that asks the user to enter how many trucks an owner is using today, whether the truck is "large" or "small" and to basically print the capacity of the trucks. I am having problems with if the user does not enter small or large after using an else statement. Professor wants us to ask the user to try again. Also, I am confused on how to print the results, especially if the user enters more than 2 trucks.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TomTrucking {


/* 
* Complete here if you are using class variables      
*/

    public static void main(String[]args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many trucks are operating today (Number of trucks must be 2 or greater)? :");
        int t1 = input.nextInt();


        if(t1 < 2) {
            System.out.println("You entered a value less than 2 for number of trucks.");
            System.out.println("Terminating program. ");
            System.exit(0);
        }else {
            double crates = 0;
            double crates1 = 0;

            String truck;
            int i=0;

            double array[] = new double[t1];
            double array1[] = new double[t1];
            for( i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {

                System.out.println("What is the size of truck " + (i+1) + "(large trucks max crates = 100, small trucks max crates = 10)? ");
                truck = input.next();

                while(!true) {
                    if(truck.equals("large")) {
                        System.out.println("What is the actual number of crates that truck " + (i+1) + " is hauling today (Truck 1 max crates is 100)? ");
                        crates = input.nextDouble();

                        boolean ok = true;
                        array[i] = (crates/100);


                    }else if(truck.equals("small")){
                        System.out.println("What is the actual number of crates that truck " + (i+1) + " is hauling today (Truck 2 max crates is 10)? ");
                        crates1 = input.nextDouble();

                        boolean ok = true;
                        array1[i] = (crates1/10)*100;


                    }else {
                        System.out.println("Enter either large or small: ");

                        boolean ok = false;


                    }
                }




                System.out.println("**Entry for all trucks completed**");    




                System.out.println("Truck " + (i-1) + " max: 100 actual: " + crates + " capacity at: " + (array[i-2]) + "%");
                System.out.println("Truck " + (i) + " max: 10 actual: " + crates1 + " capacity at: " + (array1[i-2]) + "%");

            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

first of all, the condition of the `while` loop is

```
while(!true) {
```

this means that the code inside the loop will never process. you probably meant

```
while(!ok) {
```

and this means you have to declare `ok` outside of the loop.

second, don't use `System.exit()`. It is considered bad practice. use boolean flags to control the flow.

third, I suggest you reformat your code with proper indentation and use meaningful variables names (for example for `array` and `array1`). This will help you spot bugs and help us underatnd the code. Also, break down the code into logical units and put them into separate methods.  For instance, one method deals with user input, another validates it, another for the calculation and final one to display the result.

Answer (score 0):

There are few more issues which i found, you can try

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many trucks are operating today (Number of trucks must be 2 or greater)? :");
    int totalTrucks = input.nextInt();

    if (totalTrucks < 2) {
        System.out.println("You entered a value less than 2 for number of trucks.");
        System.out.println("Terminating program. ");
        System.exit(0);
    } else {
        HashMap<Integer, Double> smallTrucks = new HashMap();
        HashMap<Integer, Double> largeTrucks = new HashMap();

        for (int i = 0; i < totalTrucks; i++) {

            System.out.println("What is the size of truck " + (i + 1) + "(large trucks max crates = 100, small trucks max crates = 10)? ");
            String truckSize = input.next();
            boolean repeatLoop = true;

            while (repeatLoop) {
                if (truckSize.equals("large")) {
                    System.out.println("What is the actual number of crates that truck " + (i + 1) + " is hauling today (Truck 1 max crates is 100)? ");
                    Double crates = input.nextDouble();
                    largeTrucks.put(i, crates);
                    repeatLoop = false;
                } else if (truckSize.equals("small")) {
                    System.out.println("What is the actual number of crates that truck " + (i + 1) + " is hauling today (Truck 2 max crates is 10)? ");

                    boolean sizeWrong=true;
                    while (sizeWrong) {
                        Double crates = input.nextDouble();
                        if (crates > 10) {
                            System.out.println("Small Truck max crates is 10,Please enter size again ");
                            repeatLoop = true;
                            continue;
                        }
                        sizeWrong=false;
                        smallTrucks.put(i, crates);

                    }
                    repeatLoop = false;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Enter either large or small: ");
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("**Entry for all trucks completed**");
        for (int i = 0; i < totalTrucks; i++) {
            Double maxTruckSize = smallTrucks.get(i);

            if (maxTruckSize != null) {
                System.out.println("Truck " + (i + 1) + " max: 100 actual: " + maxTruckSize + " capacity at: " + maxTruckSize / 100 + "%");
            }else
                System.out.println("Truck " + (i + 1) + " max: 10 actual: " + smallTrucks.get(i)+ " capacity at: " + maxTruckSize / 10 + "%");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several mistakes first correct while and move truck = input.next() inside while.

I corrected your code and I added output of running program. But if you're stick with array, you print 0 if array is not fulled with inputs. So I don't touch there. I suggest you to use ArrayList instead of array. So you can iterate only exists items.

Normal flow:

```
How many trucks are operating today (Number of trucks must be 2 or greater)? :
2
What is the size of truck 1(large trucks max crates = 100, small trucks max crates = 10)? 
large
What is the actual number of crates that truck 1 is hauling today (Truck 1 max crates is 100)? 
50
What is the size of truck 2(large trucks max crates = 100, small trucks max crates = 10)? 
small
What is the actual number of crates that truck 2 is hauling today (Truck 2 max crates is 10)? 
20
**Entry for all trucks completed**
Truck 1 max: 100 actual: 50.0 capacity at: 0.5%
Truck 2 max: 10 actual: 20.0 capacity at: 0.0%
```

If user enters a value different than "larger" or "small" it retries :

```
How many trucks are operating today (Number of trucks must be 2 or greater)? :
2
What is the size of truck 1(large trucks max crates = 100, small trucks max crates = 10)? 
xxx
Enter either large or small: 
What is the size of truck 1(large trucks max crates = 100, small trucks max crates = 10)? 
large
What is the actual number of crates that truck 1 is hauling today (Truck 1 max crates is 100)? 
50
What is the size of truck 2(large trucks max crates = 100, small trucks max crates = 10)? 
small
What is the actual number of crates that truck 2 is hauling today (Truck 2 max crates is 10)? 
20
**Entry for all trucks completed**
Truck 1 max: 100 actual: 50.0 capacity at: 0.5%
Truck 2 max: 10 actual: 20.0 capacity at: 0.0%
```

Solution :

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many trucks are operating today (Number of trucks must be 2 or greater)? :");
    int t1 = input.nextInt();

    if(t1 < 2) {
        System.out.println("You entered a value less than 2 for number of trucks.");
        System.out.println("Terminating program. ");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else {
        double crates = 0;
        double crates1 = 0;

        String truck;
        int i = 0;

        double array[] = new double[t1];
        double array1[] = new double[t1];
        for( i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {

            boolean ok = false;

            while(!ok) {
                System.out.println("What is the size of truck " + (i+1) + "(large trucks max crates = 100, small trucks max crates = 10)? ");
                truck = input.next();

                if(truck.equals("large")) {
                    System.out.println("What is the actual number of crates that truck " + (i+1) + " is hauling today (Truck 1 max crates is 100)? ");
                    crates = input.nextDouble();

                    ok = true;
                    array[i] = (crates/100);
                }
                else if(truck.equals("small")){
                    System.out.println("What is the actual number of crates that truck " + (i+1) + " is hauling today (Truck 2 max crates is 10)? ");
                    crates1 = input.nextDouble();

                    ok = true;
                    array1[i] = (crates1/10)*100;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Enter either large or small: ");

                    ok = false;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("**Entry for all trucks completed**");

        System.out.println("Truck " + (i-1) + " max: 100 actual: " + crates + " capacity at: " + (array[i-2]) + "%");
        System.out.println("Truck " + (i) + " max: 10 actual: " + crates1 + " capacity at: " + (array1[i-2]) + "%");


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the problem clearly. But just reading your code it seems there are several problem with this code, one of them is the block inside `while(!true)` will never execute. And you need to declare `boolean ok` outside the while loop. There are still some logical error with this code. But since it is your class assignment try to figure out the rest by yourself.

```
            boolean ok = false;

            while (!ok) {
                truck = input.next();

                if (truck.equals("large")) {
                    System.out.println("What is the actual number of crates that truck " + (i + 1) + " is hauling today (Truck 1 max crates is 100)? ");
                    crates = input.nextDouble();

                    ok = true;
                    array[i] = (crates / 100);


                } else if (truck.equals("small")) {
                    System.out.println("What is the actual number of crates that truck " + (i + 1) + " is hauling today (Truck 2 max crates is 10)? ");
                    crates1 = input.nextDouble();

                    ok = true;
                    array1[i] = (crates1 / 10) * 100;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Enter either large or small: ");
                }
            }
```